# Limiting ShortestPath in Cypher to nodes with specific properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to figure out how to limit a shortest path query in cypher so that it only connects "Person" nodes containing a specific property.

Here is my query:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath( (from:Person {id: 1})-[*]-(to:Person {id: 2})) RETURN p
```

I would like to limit it so that when it connects from one Person node to another Person node, the Person node has to contain a property called "job" and a value of "engineer."

Could you help me construct the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are not very clear, but if you simply want one of the people to have an `id` of 1 and the other person to be an engineer, you would use this:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath( (from:Person {id: 1})-[*]-(to:Person {job: "engineer"}))
RETURN p;
```

This kind query should be much faster if you also created indexes for the `id` and `job` properties of `Person`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry for being unclear. I see what you are saying, but I want the connections between Person ID:1 to Person ID:2 to only be through Persons with {job: "engineer"} as a property of a node. Therefore, if a connecting node does not have that job, then I do not want my shortest path to connect through them. Does that help?